# Reporting services 2008 chart X axis interval as 3 but show the first category

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In X axis of a column Chart I have a Year (for ex, "2009") and Month (for ex, "Jan") category groupings, and I would like to show just the first month of every quarter like Jan, Apr, Jul, Oct, etc.
When I specified the Interval = 3 it gives me Mar , Jun, Sep, Dec…
How can one set it so it returns the first value?

Answer (score 1):

Contacted MS support  and was given a solution, rather simple...I just had to set the following properties (using the properties windows not the chart UI ) for the Chart Axis:

Interval:3
Internal Offset:1 (this one is not present in the Axis UI just the properties window....:-s)
Margins:1